# Using JQuery to replace td data

Tags: jquery, html-table

Part of my table:

```
<th>1</th>
<td>
 <div id="div_A1">
  <a class="show-popup" href="#" data-showpopup="1" id="A1">Select This Tile</a>
 </div>
</td>
<td id="forest">
 <div id="div_A2">
  <a class="show-popup" href="#" data-showpopup="1" id="A2" >Select This Tile</a>
 </div>
</td>
<td id="forest">
 <div id="div_A3">
  <a class="show-popup" href="#" data-showpopup="1" id="A3" >Select This Tile</a>
 </div>
</td>
<td>
 <div id="div_A4">
  <a class="show-popup" href="#" data-showpopup="1" id="A4">Select This Tile</a>
 </div>
</td>
```

I have a button,

```
<div class="overlay-content popup1">
 <div class="buildings">
  <div id="navcontainer">
   <ul>
    <li><button id="attap" onclick="addattap()">Shack</button></li>
    <li><button id="shop" onclick="addshop()">Shop-house</button></li>
    <li><button id="hdb" onclick="addhdb()">HDB Flat</button></li>
    <li><button id="condo" onclick="addcondo()">Condominium</button></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <button class="close-btn">Close</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make an interface such that the program will remember which cell was clicked, and then using the button to insert an image into the corresponding  that is in the cell. I was thinking of using "event.target.id" to register the id of the cell that was clicked, and then place the image into the corresponding div with the same id name using .innerHTML.

*To make it clearer: This is a tile based game, and there are 4 types of houses that can be built. So the player clicks on a tile, say A1, and then a popup appears allowing him/her to select the house type. For example, player clicks cell A1, then chooses to build a shack, hence I am trying to display an image of a shack at cell A1. But there are cells A1-A4, hence the code should be able to recognize that the cell that the image should be on is A1, and not the other 3.*

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Is there a method to insert an image to the corresponding cell (the one which was clicked)?

Comment: You'll need to upload the image to your server, and then load it dynamically with javascript/jquery. There's no easy method for that.

Comment: ok, i'll try it out, but how do you " load it dynamically with javascript/jquery."

Comment: What does insert image mean? An image already available on server ... or upload?

Comment: the image on a server

Comment: Oh nevermind, you just want to click a cell, and then add an image you already have on your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you add a data attribute to your buttons representing the image you want to add -

```
$('.show-popup').click (function (){
  $(this).data ('clicked', true);
});

$('button').click (function (){
    $('[data-clicked=true]').parents ('div').html ('<img src="'+$(this).data ('img-src')+'"/>');
});
```

Comment: but there are 4 different images, and there are 4 buttons, so I am trying to link the button to a specific image. Eg: Cell clicked is A1, button clicked is "Shack", so insert an image of a shack into the cell.

Comment: maybe you could explain your code a bit? you see question asker has a lot of questions

Comment: I updated based on the comments and question update.  I'm answering from my phone though, so I'm kind of at my limit for detail.  I hope this at least gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cellClicked;
$("td").click(function(){
    cellClicked = $(this).children("div");
});
$("button").click(function(){
    cellClicked.html("<img src='some_image.jpg' />");
});
```

i assume you want 4 different images depending on the type you click so add the cellClicked.html line in each of your 4 onclick functions (addattap(), addshop(), addhdb(), addcondo()) assigning different jpg.

Comment: `cellClicked` is a jQuery object .. has no innerHTML property

Answer (score 0):

You can use the element ID to determine which image

```
$('.show-popup').click(function(){
    // "this" is element click occurred on
    var id = this.id;
    var $img=$('<img>',{src: '/imgname' + id +'.jpg'});
    $(this).replaceWith($img);
});
```

this example assumes that the id is in the image filename. Adjust according to needs

Depending on your overall goals it might be easier to toggle a class on the elements and set image using css